# keycloak - SSL error: Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, jboss, keycloak

I am running a keycloak instance connected to Amazon RDS Postgres with this docker command:

```
docker run --rm --name keycloak \
-p 9090:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=xxx \
-e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=xxx \
-e DB_VENDOR=postgres \
-e DB_ADDR=mydb2.xxx.rds.amazonaws.com:5432 \
-e DB_USER=xxx \
-e DB_PASSWORD=xxx \
-e DB_DATABASE=keycloak \
jboss/keycloak:latest
```

But it cannot connect to the DB:

```
05:18:54,776 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "keycloak-server.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"keycloak-server.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003325: Failed to construct public org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication(javax.servlet.ServletContext,org.jboss.resteasy.core.Dispatcher)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003325: Failed to construct public org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication(javax.servlet.ServletContext,org.jboss.resteasy.core.Dispatcher)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to connect to database
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS
    Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS
    Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
    Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: SSL error: Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints
    Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints
    Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Algorithm constraints check failed on keysize limits. RSA 1024bit key used with certificate: C=US, ST=Washington, L=Seattle, O=Amazon.com, OU=RDS, CN=mydb2.xxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com.  Usage was tls server"}}
```

I am sure about the following:

- The RDS instance is available, the port is open. I checked it with `psql`.
- This happens with the `jboss/keycloak:7.0.1` and does not happen with `jboss/keycloak:7.0.0`. Version `7.0.0` works fine.

Why can this happen and how to fix it?

This probably is too broad a question, but I am not a Java guy (I mostly do Python), so this is as narrow as I can do.

Comment: are your an instance in public subnet or instance have internet access? are  trying to connect with RDS using TLS?https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-7998?_sscc=t

Comment: yes, my instance has internet access. I checked it with psql.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same issue. Been running against RDS for weeks without issue using `7.0.0`

Breaks in `7.0.1` and `8.0.0` with the above error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like is said in [Jan Garaj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58853994/1134865) different Java versions are used.

This is failing because the RSA key used by RDS is only 1024 bits long while `java.security` only allows keys longer than 1024 bits.

Updating your RDS to the new certificate authority (`rds-ca-2019`) seems to create longer keys and fix this issue.

[AWS has documentation on how to do this.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL-certificate-rotation.html)

Comment: do you know what can I do when using an azure postgres database?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a problem with Java security. There are used different Java versions (1.8 vs 11), so it may need some tweaks in `java.security` or cipher configuration on RDS side (if is possible):

You can compare and tweak 7.0.1 `java.security` file:

```
$ docker run --rm -ti --entrypoint bash jboss/keycloak:7.0.1 \
  -c 'cat /etc/java/java-11-openjdk/java-11-openjdk-*/conf/security/java.security | grep -v ^# | grep -v ^$'

$ docker run --rm -ti --entrypoint bash jboss/keycloak:7.0.0 \
  -c 'cat /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-*/jre/lib/security/java.security | grep -v ^# | grep -v ^$'
```